# mount vue multiselect to newly generated component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to mount vue-multiselect to the fields that can be generated by javascript. To identify between fields. I created suffix on every id as `#metric1_{numhere}`. Vue successfully mounts for `#metric1_1` but won't work for any new elements like `#metric1_2`.

```
metricVue = new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
    value: { key: 'ctr', value: 'CTR' },
    options: toKeysValues(metricNames)
  },
  methods: {
    customLabel (option) {
      return `${option.value}`
    }
  }
});


function addVues(vc){
  metricVue.$mount('#metric1_'+vc);
}
```

Comment: function addVues(vc){
  new Vue({...}).$mount('#metric1_'+vc);
}

Comment: @jacky, that worked, can you post it as answer for the community please?

Answer (score 0):

okey，Every time you mount a Vue instance, you need to rebuild a new Vue instance, instead of using the same Vue instance over and over again.

```
function addVues(vc){ 
  new Vue({...}).$mount('#metric1_'+vc); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be improved with some explanatory text. Why and how does this fix the OP's problem?

Comment: I think when you look at the code, you'll get the idea.It's not too complicated